# Confluent HDFS connector: How can I read from the latest offset when there are no hdfs files?

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We have a producer application that is running for a few days now and is producing data to topicA. We want to start hdfs connector to read from topicA but NOT from offset 0 (Since this will result in a huge lag). We want to start from the **latest** offset (There's new data coming into topicA all the time).

1) Since the connector gets offset information from topic names in hdfs, how can we read from latest offset since there are no files that exist in hdfs?

2) One option I can think of is manually creating dummy files with latest offsets for each partition but we're talking about 60 partitions in topicA here so is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NoName](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6656192/noname), the ability of the HDFS Connector to reset to the latest committed offset in the absence of file names in HDFS was added recently.

You will find it in versions 4.0.1 or 4.1.0 and later.

HDFS connector is a sink connector that manages consumer offsets itself. It's designed to do so in order to achieve exactly-once semantics when exporting files to HDFS. In versions previous to the above, if the connector didn't find any files in HDFS it would start consuming from the earliest offset of the topic, regardless of any consumer settings.

You may find the related changes that now allow the connector to consult the committed offsets in the absence of files in HDFS here:

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/pull/299 
and
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/pull/305

Answer (score 1):

You can set this property to make your consumer group of connect start from the latest available offset in the topic

```
consumer.auto.offset.reset=latest
```

Although, Connect usually catches up fairly quickly with a large cluster and 1 task per partition, so starting from the earliest shouldn't be that bad

Comment: Thank you! Where do I set this? I tried setting it in the connector properties file but I still see `auto.offset.reset = earliest` in `ConsumerConfig values`

Comment: Personally, I set it in the Worker properties, but you should also be able to set in within the specific task properties. Note: I have only tested this with S3 Connect

Comment: Okay. I was able to set it in the worker properties file and it shows up on the consumerConfigs. I deleted all the hdfs files (so that it has no offset info in the filename) and I started connector but I still see it reading from offset 0 and not the last offset. I ran `bin/kafka-consumer-groups` with --describe option to check the current_offset.

Comment: Which version of Confluent are you using? I think 4.0 refactored some of the HDFS logic

Comment: I'm using 4.0.0 version of Confluent

Comment: Hmm. Like I said, I've only verified this setting works on S3 Connect. I assume you saw this comment? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837808/camus-migration-kafka-hdfs-connect-does-not-start-from-the-set-offset#comment86735651_49841730